# How do I integrate this term?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ , $u\in C^1(\Omega)$ , $\phi \in C^{\infty}_0(\Omega) $ a test function .

$\int_{\Omega}\nabla |u| \phi dx=-\int_{\Omega}|u|\nabla\phi dx=-\int_{\{x\in\Omega|u>0\}}u\nabla\phi dx+\int_{\{x\in\Omega|u<0\}}u\nabla\phi dx=\int_{\{x\in\Omega|u>0\}}\nabla u\phi dx-\int_{\{x\in\Omega|u<0\}}\nabla u\phi dx$

Why does the first and third equation hold ?

Comment: Could you show what happens when you use integration by parts to move the $\nabla$ from $|u|$ to $\phi$ in the first integral?

Comment: I think I have to use this $\int_{\Omega}\nabla \cdot u(x)\phi(x)dx=\int_{\partial \Omega} u(x) \nu\phi(x)d\sigma_x-\int_{\Omega}\  u(x)\nabla \phi(x)dx$